# Gracefully shutting down system tray application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very basic application that runs in the system tray (notification area).  The `Main` method looks like this:

```
using (NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon())
{
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(
        "Exit", 
        null, 
        delegate { App.Exit(); }
        )
    );

    notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;

    Application.Run();
}
```

So far this works fine (I can use the Exit option in the context menu and the application properly exits.  However, I need to exit the application when the software is uninstalled.  Right now I'm using `taskkill` from my WiX installer to do this (maybe there is a better way?).  The problem is that if I do `taskkill /im myapp.exe` the icon in the notification area disappears but the process is still running.  If I force close it with `taskkill /f /im myapp.exe` then the process ends but the icon lingers (until I hover my mouse over it).  Is there a way to remove the icon and end the process from a separate process?

Comment: You need to tell your application to exit, so it can un-register from the systemtray.  taskkill just unloads the process from memory, the process has no chance of doing anything in response.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden form to your application. It will be an argument to Application.Run(). When the form closes your app will exit.

To get the form to close in WiX us a util:CloseApplication[1](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_closeapplication.htm) with the CloseMessage attribute set to true.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot.  FYI, for anyone else: I created an invisible form by setting the `ShowInTaskbar` property to `false` and the `WindowState` to `FormWindowState.Minimized` on a newly constructed form just before calling `Application.Run(myForm)`.

Comment: OK, after further testing this doesn't always work.  If I bring up the context menu before attempting to close the app the icon disappears but the process continues to run.  If I don't right-click and bring up the context menu everything works great.  Any idea what is going on?  The context menu itself seems pretty innocuous...

Comment: It could be that the icon and menu controls need a container that's run in the message loop so they'll be unloaded before the message loop terminates. Try using the WinForm designer to place the icon and menu on the form. They will still show even though their containing form is hidden.

Comment: OK, good idea but that still doesn't work.  I tried to examine this a little closer with the debugger and it looks like `Application.Run` is still going (even though the notification icon is gone).  It's almost as if the context menu takes over for the main form of the application or something?  But that wouldn't explain how the notification icon is removed... this is really weird.

Comment: Just to add some more info to my previous comment, I overrode the WndProc method on my form and set a breakpoint in it to see what would happen.  Without opening the context menu I get a bunch of messages when I use taskkill.  However, if I do open the context menu and then call taskkill I don't get anything.  I suspect the context menu is somehow taking over as the main form for the process?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a different approach.  I added a command line parameter to indicate that I want to shutdown.  This switch would then call the Win32 API `SendMessage` (oddly `PostMessage` didn't work) with a custom message defined with `RegisterWindowMessage`.  The WiX installer would then execute process with this command line parameter and things are properly shutdown now.  What a serious pain...